# What's the underlying reason of only having "Okay, I got it" in modal notification windows?

Tags: notification, modal-windows

Modal notification windows are usually designed like this:

[image: 1]

*An example taken from Stack Exchange chat*

A common feature of these modal notification windows is that there is a button roughly saying "Okay, I understood", and nothing else that you can close the window, including the typical "cross button on the top right corner". The implication seems to be that I'm forced to show that I understood it (otherwise it'll block the space and hence whatever I intended to do) even when I might not, or that I don't really care and I just want to close it.

What's the design purpose of these kind of window with the only option of "Okay, I understood"?

Answer (score 3):

You said it yourself - " I'm forced to show that I understood it". Usually this is the context of rules/policies/terms of use, so you do want the user to be "forced" to agree to the rules before using the website/service/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's a legal reason. You deliberately took an action. It's the same reason that Anti-spam legislation forces you to deliberately check a box to receive a newsletter or other correspondence.